# No Module Named ServerSocket

Tags: python

I am trying to follow Example 20.17.4.1. SocketServer.TCPServer from [Python Docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socketserver.html). But I get an error:

```
ImportError: No module named 'ServerSocket'
```

I am using new version of Python and use IDLE for editing and executing the script. Need help to get rid of this error.

Comment: I tried also with `import SocketServer` instead of ServerSocket. No Luck :( @bamboon

Comment: are you using python 2 or python 3? it has been renamed in python 3 to `socketserver`

Comment: I am using Python 3 and I am on windows 7. socketserver worked. EVERYTHING IN LOWER CASE. Thanks @bamboon

Comment: @bamboon you should post that as an answer :)

Comment: Also, Romaan, try to avoid reading the documentation of a software with a different major version number. Between python2.5 and python2.6 there are not so many differences, but between python2.x and python3.x there were *many* changes, and a lot of them were not backward compatible. The same is valid for any software. Major version change is usually related to backward incompatible changes.

Answer (score 121, accepted):

The right name is `SocketServer` in Python2 and `socketserver` in Python3.

Comment: And socketserver is a standard library module in Python 3 so you don't need to install it.

Answer (score 12):

If you are using python 3 it is available as socketserver (all lowercase)

Answer (score 4):

In the code I have It already tried importing SocketServer and socketserver but neither work.

```
try:
    import SocketServer as socketserver
    from BaseHTTPServer import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler
except ImportError:
    import socketserver
    from http.server import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler
```

However after I can this command it worked for me

```
$pip install Werkzeug --upgrade
```

Answer (score 3):

I got the same problem, which was resolved by uninstalling and installing the Flask and Werkzeug again

1) pip uninstall Flask
2) pip uninstall Werkzeug

3) pip install Flask
4) pip install Werkzeug

Answer (score -1):

> 1. pip uninstall Flask 2) pip uninstall Werkzeug
> 2. pip install Flask 4) pip install Werkzeug

Didn't work for me. I end up reinstalling odoo 13 every single time. Although I've noticed that this occurs only when I add odoo/addons as a source map in pycharm.

Edit: I finally found the issue!
If you're using pycharm and have odoo/addons added in your Content Root, try removing it from the content root and re-run the server. Hope it helps someone

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29891650)