# Web streaming using Raspberry pi 3 model b and picam

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3

I am trying to stream video in web using Raspi cam. I am using a code from internet but it has an error and it shows this,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "picam.py", line 8, in <module>
    import socketserver
ImportError: No module named socketserver
```

I don't know what to do. Help me please? THANKYOUUUU!
The code I'm using is in http://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/latest/recipes2.html#web-streaming
(4.10 WEB STREAMING)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You are most probably using Python2 which has `SocketServer`.

I'll recommend that you use Python3 which has `socketserver`.

Reference -> [No Module Named ServerSocket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13329761/no-module-named-serversocket)

Comment: I'm already using Raspberry Pi 3 model B but it's not working.

Comment: I am talking about the Python Version, which you can see by opening the terminal and typing `python`. If it's is 2.x.x then try python3, otherwise lookup a guide to install Python 3.
Also to check, once in `python` shell, try `import SocketServer` and `import socketserver`.